# Create columns of array values based on multiple conditions on column from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python. I need to create a dataframe column - (array-like) based on condition and extract it from other dataframe.

df-

```
Date         A    App   T
1/12/2018    1    ABC   1
1/13/2018    2    DDC   2
1/14/2018    3    SDC   3
1/15/2018    4    MDC   4
1/16/2018    1    ABC   8
```

df2-

```
A     H    App
1     H1   ABC
1     H2   ABC
1     H3   ABC
1     H4   ABC
2     H5   DDC
2     H1   DDC
3     H2   SDC
3     H5   SDC
4     H3   MDC
```

Desired Result-

I need to add another column (OtherApp) to df as below (Just few samples are shown)-

```
Date       A    App T   OtherApp
1/12/2018  1    ABC 1  [DDC,SDC,MDC]  
1/13/2018  2    DDC 2  [ABC,SDC]
1/14/2018  3    SDC 3  [ABC,DDC]
1/15/2018  4    MDC 4  [ABC]
```

Logic behind this -

1. Take  A for each value T (unique- valued column) column from df .
2. Match the A with df2 data and get all the H associated to the particular A value.
3. Get all the App hosted in the H values obtained from step-2.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please post data as text, not images. We can't copy and paste from this.

Comment: Sorry, didn't knew images create issue for Copy + Paste. I tried a for loop for each record in df and used a loc functionality inside to get the list of values of H from df2, but it doesn't too right and was not able to obtain the list of values of H.

Comment: Please edit your post to add the code you have tried, its difficult for us to see where your issue is without your code. But for output 1 you can try: `idx, unique_values = np.unique(df.A,return_index=True)`